# In R, convert list into stringified JSON for body of POST request

Tags: r, stringify, jsonlite

```
output_goal <- '{ "firstName": "Tim", "lastName": "Jones", "team": { "value":104290, "teamMarket": "Card", "gender": "MALE" }}'

zed1 <- list(firstName = 'Tim', lastName = 'Jones', team = list(value = 104290, teamMarket = 'Card', gender = 'MALE'))
output <- jsonlite::toJSON(zed1)
output <- gsub('\\[', '', output)
output <- gsub('\\]', '', output)
output == output_goal
> FALSE


zed2 <- list(firstName = 'Tim', lastName = 'Jones', team = data.frame(value = 104290, teamMarket = 'Card', gender = 'MALE'))
output <- jsonlite::toJSON(zed2)
output <- gsub('\\[', '', output)
output <- gsub('\\]', '', output)
output == output_goal
> FALSE
```

Our goal is to convert either of `zed1`, `zed2` into the string `output_goal`. So far, we have tried to use `jsonlite::toJSON`, and then gsub to remove the brackets. I believe that we are struggling with escape characters, but am not sure what else to try to get these strings to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`auto_unbox`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.8.4/topics/toJSON%2C%20fromJSON) parameter:

> `auto_unbox`: Automatically unbox() all atomic vectors of length 1.

```r
jsonlite::toJSON(zed1, auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"firstName":"Tim","lastName":"Jones","team":{"value":104290,"teamMarket":"Card","gender":"MALE"}}
```

Note the warning in the docs though:

> It is usually safer to avoid this and instead use the unbox() function to unbox individual elements. An exception is that objects of class AsIs (i.e. wrapped in I()) are not automatically unboxed. This is a way to mark single values as length-1 arrays.

Depending on the complexity of your real data you may want to use [`unbox()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/jsonlite/html/unbox.html) function on those elements you know are length one.

Comment: Yes this leads to a string that we can utilize in our POST request. Thank you.